# Unable to append multiple value to a cell in excel using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Below is the sample code where I am trying to append multiple values to single Cell in Worksheet but the Cell is only geting updated with a single value .

My $exportpolicyrules have data in below format

```
PolicyName    RuleIndex    ClientMatch      
policy1             1     server1,server2,server3,server4 
policy2             2     server5,server6,server6,server7


foreach($i in $exportpolicyrules)
{
    $x = $i.ClientMatch.Split(',')

    $WS.Cells.item($row,12) +=  $x

}
```

I tried to save $i.ClientMatch to $WS.Cells.item($row,12) but that not updating anything hence tried with splitting each element and append it but its updating only a single value.Any suggestions please.

Comment: $WS.Cells.item($row,12).Value2 +=  $x

Comment: @f6a4 it updated server1,server5,server6,server6,server7 . server2--3---4 are missing in cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd first

- iterate, split and gather data (avoiding the inefficient `+=`)
- then eventually sort unique to remove duplicates
- and finally join the items and save to the cell.

---

```
$exportpolicyrules = @'
"PolicyName","RuleIndex","ClientMatch"
"policy1","1","server1,server2,server3,server4"
"policy2","2","server5,server6,server6,server7"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$x = foreach($i in $exportpolicyrules){
    $i.ClientMatch.Split(',')
}
($x | Sort -Unique ) -join ','

# $WS.Cells.item($row,12).Value2 = ($x | Sort -Unique ) -join ','
```

sample output (the double server6 is removed):

```
server1,server2,server3,server4,server5,server6,server7
```